# java callback to javascript, params lost "\", and json parse error

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

this issue boring me now
 the json string in java is:

```
{"code":1,"result":0,"data":"{\"account\":\"10001\",\"token\":\"73aa6a8d6f624c5184dfedbb085ef116\"}"}
```

but the str received in javascript is:

```
{"code":1,"result":0,"data":"{"account":"10001","token":"73aa6a8d6f624c5184dfedbb085ef116"}"}
```

the java callback method is

[image]

and the html's js function is this:

[image]

I tried stringfy, json.parse, eval, but they not work, I always receive json parse error, plz help

Answer (score 0):

Your original java json string is wrong, the

```
  "data":{"key1":value1}
```

And if you want to check if your json format is correct or not, suggest using http://json.parser.online.fr/   this is a good website, help you to find the error very quickly.

```
wrong:
    {"code":1,"result":0,"data":"{\"account\":\"10001\",\"token\":\"73aa6a8d6f624c5184dfedbb085ef116\"}"}

correct:
    {"code":1,"result":0,"data":{\"account\":\"10001\",\"token\":\"73aa6a8d6f624c5184dfedbb085ef116\"}}
```

Comment: but the link you provided didn't show any error about the java wrong json data, but the corrent json shows

Comment: You still don't know your java error?
should be this {"code":1,"result":0,"data":{\"account\"

Comment: remove the " after data , the link is using to verify json string, not to verify java string